# Uniform Continuity on $D$ and Boundedness on $D$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I have to prove or find an counterexample  of the statement: if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$ then $f$ is bounded on $D$.

I think this statement is not true since if $f(x)=x$ is uniformly continuous on $D=\Bbb R$ but not bounded on it. Am I right to assume that $D$ can be the whole $\Bbb R$? Are there any other classical examples?

Thank you,
Klara

Comment: Well, does the original question put any restrictions on D?

Comment: @ Mike No it does not

Comment: @Klara: What kind of counterexample are you looking for? As it stands, you've already answered the given question.

Comment: @ WJ32 I was looking for other counterexamples and If it legit to have D=R, I think that D=R is the only scenario when uniform continuity is not bounded.Do you agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f(x)=x$ and $D=(-\infty,a) \cup (b,+\infty), \ a<b,$  $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$ and not bounded on it.

Maybe you are looking for a bounded set $D$ s.t. $f$ is uniformly continuous and unbounded on $D$. You cannot find such $f$.

Or (equivalently) if you are asking:

What are the conditions on $D$ such that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$ then $f$ is bounded?

then the answer is $$\text{$D$ must be bounded.}$$

For the proof we will use the following

If f is [uniformly continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity) on $D$ then f is [Cauchy-continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-continuous_function) on D.

Or, if you want, if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$ then sends Cauchy sequences on $D$ to Cauchy sequences.

Now suppose that $D$ is bounded and $f$ is uniformly continuous and unbounded on $D$. Then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find an $x_n \in D$ such that $|f(x_n)|>n$. (Obviously) $f(x_n)$ does not have a Cauchy subsequence. Since $D$ is bounded and $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq D \Rightarrow (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded so from [Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) it has a Cauchy subsequence, lets say $(x_{k_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  $. So we  found a Cauchy sequence $(x_{k_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  $ such that $f(x_{k_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  $ is not Cauchy. Contradiction.